PWA gigantic performance difference between Chrome V8 and Safari WebKit
On non Safari WebKit engine(Windows or Android browsers), our app runs flawlessly, but on iPhone and Mac, it takes literally 600% degraded performance to render our WebComponents.
Check the UX Benchamarks:
Android - 6 seconds https://imgur.com/a/FlC0Apn
Windows - 6 seconds https://imgur.com/TivxVVB
Mac - 1 minute + (1.5x speed because of imgur limitations) https://imgur.com/gUUua4i
iPhone - 1 minute + (2x speed because of imgur limitations) https://imgur.com/uULsPae
or you can quickly check yourself by accesing the PWA at https://colmeio.com/config
All our WebComponents are designed the same way this one was:
class Topic extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.classList.add('skeleton');
  }
  render(){
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <style>
      @import url('./asset/chunk/style.min.css');
      @import url('./asset/~external/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css');
      :host(.skeleton){ height: ${this.getAttribute('height') ?? 'var(--height-input)'}; }
      :host(.skeleton) .drawIn{ display: none; }
      :host{ 
        display: flex; 
        width: ${this.getAttribute('width') ?? '100%'};
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      :host([disable]) .topicHeader{
        cursor: not-allowed;
      }
      :host([disable]) .topicBase{
        background-color: var(--color-disable-0);
        color: var(--color-disable-1);
      }
      :host([disable]) .topicHeader{
        background-color: unset;
        color: unset;
      }
      :host([disable]) #startIcon{ color: var(--color-disable-1); }
      :host([disable]) .headerText{ --text-color: var(--color-disable-1); }
      :host([disable]) #endIcon{ color: var(--color-disable-1); }
      .topicBase{
        display: flex;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: ${this.getAttribute('width') ?? '100%'};
        min-height: ${this.getAttribute('height') ?? 'var(--height-input)'};
      }
      .topicBase.displayed .drawIn{ 
        padding: ${this.hasAttribute('void') ? '10px 0 0 0' : '15px 5px 5px 5px'};
      }
      .topicBase.displayed{ box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-0); }
      .topicBase.displayed:hover{ box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-1); }
      #startIcon{ 
        font-size: ${this.getAttribute('startIconSize') ?? '24px'};
        color: var(--color-contrast); 
      }
      #endIcon{
        font-size: ${this.getAttribute('endIconSize') ?? '20px'};
        color: var(--color-contrast); 
      }
      .topicHeader{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: fit-content;
        cursor: pointer; 
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: ${this.hasAttribute('color') ? 'var(--color-1)' : 'var(--color-soft-5)'};
        box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-0);
        height: ${this.getAttribute('height') ?? 'var(--height-input)'};
        width: 100%;
      }
      .topicHeader:hover{ 
        background: ${this.hasAttribute('color') ? 'var(--color-3)' : 'var(--color-soft-10)'};
        box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-1);
      }
      .topicHeader.color{ background: var(--color-1); }
      .topicHeader.color:hover{ background: var(--color-3); }
      .drawIn{
        position: relative;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 0fr;
        transition: grid-template-rows 0.1s linear, transform 0.1s linear;
        transform: translateY(14px);
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 24px;
        /* z-index: 2; */
        width: 100%;
      }
      .drawIn.displayed{ grid-template-rows: 1fr; transform: translateY(0); }
      .drawIn.shorten{ margin-top: 0; z-index: 0;}
      .drawInContent{ 
        overflow: hidden; 
      }
      .drawInContent.displayed{ overflow: visible; }
      .drawIn.displayed .contentWidth, .drawInContent.displayed .contentWidth{ visibility: visible; }
      .contentWidth{
        visibility: invisible;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: ${this.getAttribute('max-width-inner') ?? '100%'};
      }
      .loadingIcon{
        position:absolute;
        min-width:  100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        inset: 0; 
      }
    </style>
    <div class="w100p topicBase rel">
      <!-- Topic Content -->
      <div class="drawIn">
        <div class="drawInContent display-flex-v-center">
          <div class="contentWidth display-flex-v-center gap5" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flexCenterH topicHeader pdg5">
        <div class="w100p flexLeft startHeader">
          <div class="loadingIcon"></div>
          <div class="flexLeft flexCenterH msg gap5">
            <i id="startIcon" class="${this.getAttribute('icon') ?? 'bi-caret-down-fill'}"></i>
            <s-span class="headerText display-flex-v-center" lineHeight="26px">${this.getAttribute('placeholder') ?? ''}</s-span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rel display-flex-v-center"><i id="endIcon" class="bi-caret-down-fill"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>`;
    // Get component inner elements
    this.topic         = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.topicBase');
    this.header        = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.topicHeader');
    this.drawIn        = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.drawIn');
    this.startHeader   = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.startHeader');
    this.startIcon     = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#startIcon');
    this.endIcon       = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#endIcon');
    this.drawInContent = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.drawInContent');
    this.headerText    = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('s-span');
    this.headerSpace   = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.headerSpace');
    this.msg           = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.msg');
    this.loading       = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.loadingIcon');
    this.contentWidth  = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.contentWidth');
    // Set component inner elements
    if(this.hasAttribute('displayed')){ this.show(); }
    if(this.hasAttribute('shorten')){ this.drawIn.classList.add('shorten'); }
    // s-topic events
    this.header.addEventListener('click', e =>{
      if(this.hasAttribute('disable')){ return; }
      if(this.drawIn.classList.contains('displayed')){ this.hide(); } 
      else{ this.show(); }
    });
  }
  draw(){
    this.classList.remove('skeleton');
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('render'));
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.render();
    setTimeout(e =>{ requestAnimationFrame(e =>{ this.draw(); }); }, 0);
  }
  disable(disableMessage = 0){ 
    this.setAttribute('disable', ''); 
    if(disableMessage){
      this.onclick = e =>{
        if(this.hasAttribute('disable')){
          msgBox({ title: 'Desabilitado', inner: disableMessage });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  enable(){ this.removeAttribute('disable'); }
  show(){
    if(this.hasAttribute('disable')){ return; }
    if(this.hasAttribute('shorten')){ this.header.style.width = 'fit-content'; }
    this.drawIn.style.willChange = 'grid-template-rows, transform';
    this.topic.style.willChange = 'box-shadow';
    requestAnimationFrame(e =>{
      this.drawIn.classList.add('displayed');
      this.endIcon.classList = this.swapTopicIcon(this.endIcon.classList.value, 0);
      setTimeout(e => { 
        this.drawInContent.classList.add('displayed'); 
        this.drawIn.style.willChange = 'auto';
        this.topic.style.willChange = 'auto';
      }, 100);
      this.topic.classList.add('displayed');
    });
    // Add event on show
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('show'));
  }  
  hide(){
    this.drawIn.style.willChange = 'grid-template-rows, transform';
    this.topic.style.willChange = 'box-shadow';
    requestAnimationFrame(e =>{
      this.drawIn.classList.remove('displayed');
      this.endIcon.classList = this.swapTopicIcon(this.endIcon.classList.value, 1);
      this.drawInContent.classList.remove('displayed');
      setTimeout(e => { 
        this.drawInContent.classList.remove('displayed'); 
        this.drawIn.style.willChange = 'auto';
        this.topic.style.willChange = 'auto';
      }, 100); // just in case call show and hide in less the 100ms
      this.topic.classList.remove('displayed');
    });
  }
  color(color){
    if(!color){ color = ''; } // black
    this.endIcon.style.color = `${color}`;
    this.headerText.style.color = `${color}`;
  }
  setHeader(header){ this.headerText.innerHTML = header; }
  showLoading(){
    this.headerText.innerHTML = '';
    this.endIcon.classList = 'bi-arrow-repeat';
  }
  showLoading(xsize = 35, ysize = 35){
    this.loading.innerHTML = '<div class="cssload-wrap"><div class="cssload-cssload-spinner" style="--xsize:'+xsize+'px; --ysize:'+ysize+'px;"></div>'
    this.msg.style.opacity = '0';
  }
  hideLoading(){
    this.loading.innerHTML = '';
    this.msg.style.opacity = '1';
  }
  swapTopicIcon = (actualIcon, origin) =>{
    if(this.hasAttribute('shorten') && origin === 0){
      this.header.classList.add('color');
      this.startHeader.style.display = 'none';
      this.header.style.width = 'fit-content';
      return 'bi-caret-up-fill'; 
    }
    else if(this.hasAttribute('shorten') && origin === 1){
      this.header.classList.remove('color');
      this.startHeader.style.display = 'flex';
      this.header.style.width = '100%';
      return 'bi-caret-down-fill'; 
    }
    if(actualIcon === 'bi-caret-down-fill' && origin === 0){ return 'bi-caret-up-fill'; }
    else if(actualIcon === 'bi-caret-up-fill' && origin === 1)   { return 'bi-caret-down-fill'; }
    if(actualIcon === 'bi-arrow-down-right-square' && origin === 0){ return 'bi-arrow-up-square'; }
    else if(actualIcon === 'bi-arrow-up-square' && origin === 1)   { return 'bi-arrow-down-right-square'; }
    else{ return actualIcon; }
  }
  set(configObj = 0){
    if(configObj.hasOwnProperty('icon')){ this.startIcon.className = configObj.icon; }
    if(configObj.hasOwnProperty('color')){
      let boxShadow;
      if(configObj.color === 'red'){ 
        configObj.color = 'var(--color-red)';
        boxShadow = 'var(--box-shadow-red)';
      }
      this.startIcon.style.color = `${configObj.color}`;
      this.endIcon.style.color = `${configObj.color}`;
      this.headerText.style = `--text-color: ${configObj.color}`;
      // this.topic.style.boxShadow = boxShadow;
      this.header.style.boxShadow = boxShadow;
    }
    else{ 
      // Back to original colors
      this.startIcon.style.color = 'var(--color-contrast)';
      this.endIcon.style.color = 'var(--color-contrast)';
      this.headerText.style = '--text-color: unset';
      this.header.style.boxShadow = 'var(--box-shadow-0)';
    }
  }
}
customElements.define('s-topic', Topic);

So, like this customElements:<s-topic></s-topic> we have more than 50 others like <s-popup></s-popup> and so on [...] which took a fair amount of time to develop. In the beggining, even v8 had trouble rendering them but then we adjust the heavily nested WebComponents by using  properly and calculating all dimentions while the component has el.style.display = none; then switching to el.style.display = flex; or block, table, inline, ... when we desire to render them as follows:
  draw(){
    this.classList.remove('skeleton');
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('render'));
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.render();
    setTimeout(e =>{ requestAnimationFrame(e =>{ this.draw(); }); }, 0);
  }

as shown in the exemple, so the heavily nested WebComponents draws in a single paint on Chrome v8 engine, for exemple. This tecnic does not seens to work on Safari WebKit and I wonder if I will have success using my WebComponents hybridly on both Safari and Chrome engines.
One other thing which reduces our renderization performance is loading our JS Chuncks on demand and integrating them by calling this pattern:
async function initConfigPOP(){
  configPopupHTML = `
    <s-popup id="configPOP" placeholder="Configurações" url="config" area="menuPOP" max-width="800px" max-width-inner="600px">
      <!-- Device Config -->
      <s-topic id="deviceConfigsConfigTPC" icon="bi-house-gear" placeholder="Configurações do Dispositivo"></s-topic>
      <!-- User Config -->
      <s-topic id="userConfigsConfigTPC" icon="bi-person-gear" placeholder="Configurações do Usuário"></s-topic>
      <!-- Logout User -->
      <div class="display-flex-v-center w100p rel" style="max-height: var(--height-button);">
        <s-signature></s-signature>
        <div class="abs w100p display-none"><s-button id="logoutUserConfigBTN" danger class="mgn-l-auto"><i class="bi bi-power"></i>Sair<div></div></s-button></div>
      </div>
    </s-popup>
  `.trim();
  // Create a temporary div to hold all page HTML
  let tempDIV = document.createElement('div');
  tempDIV.style.display = 'none';
  tempDIV.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', configPopupHTML);
 
  // Append all Chunks into the fragment
  insertDeviceConfigsConfigHTML(tempDIV);
  insertUserConfigsConfigHTML(tempDIV);

[...]
function insertDeviceConfigsConfigHTML(tempDIV){
  let deviceConfigsHTML = `
    <!-- Device Info -->
    <div id="deviceInfoConfigDIV" class="display-flex-h-center-center w100p border-radius-5 box-shadow hover-soft pdg5 gap5 cursor-pointer bg-soft color-disable" style="height: 34px;" title="Informações do Dispositivo">
      <i id="deviceInfoConfigIcon" class="icon-default"></i>
      <s-span id="deviceInfoTypeConfigSPN" style="min-width: fit-content;"></s-span>
      <s-span id="deviceInfoConfigSPN" showTitle noWrap></s-span>
    </div>
    <s-checkbox id="pushNotificationsConfigCB" switch disable>Notificações</s-checkbox>
    <s-checkbox id="themeToggleConfigCB" switch>Modo Noturno</s-checkbox>
    <s-checkbox id="disableBarMovementConfigCB" switch>Ocultação das Barras</s-checkbox>
  `.trim();
  let deviceConfigsConfigTPC = tempDIV.querySelector('#deviceConfigsConfigTPC');
  deviceConfigsConfigTPC.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', deviceConfigsHTML);
}
async function runDeviceConfigsConfig(){
  // Get Elements
  window.deviceInfoConfigDIV        = document.getElementById('deviceInfoConfigDIV');
  window.deviceInfoConfigIcon       = document.getElementById('deviceInfoConfigIcon');
  window.deviceInfoTypeConfigSPN    = document.getElementById('deviceInfoTypeConfigSPN');
[...]

then:
function insertUserInfoConfigHTML(tempDIV){
  let userInfoConfigHTML = `
    <s-input id="nameUserInfoConfigINP" model="name" header="Nome Completo"></s-input>
    <s-input id="emailUserInfoConfigINP" model="email"></s-input>
    <s-input id="birthUserInfoConfigINP" model="birth"></s-input>
    <s-input id="telUserInfoConfigINP" model='tel'></s-input>
    <!-- Gender -->
    <s-box header="Gênero" horizontal>
      <s-checkbox id="womanUserInfoConfigCB" onclick="tagGenderConfig(this)" height="30px" group>Mulher</s-checkbox>
      <s-checkbox id="manUserInfoConfigCB" onclick="tagGenderConfig(this)" height="30px" group>Homem</s-checkbox>
      <s-checkbox id="otherUserInfoConfigCB" onclick="tagGenderConfig(this)" height="30px" group>Outro</s-checkbox>
    </s-box>
    <!-- Update User Info -->
    <s-button id="submitUserInfoConfigBTN" class="w100p" disable>Atualizar Informações</s-button>
  `.trim();
  let userInfoConfigTPC = tempDIV.querySelector('#userInfoConfigTPC');
  userInfoConfigTPC.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', userInfoConfigHTML);
}
async function runUserInfoConfig(){
  console.log('Loading User Info Config');
  userInfoConfigTPC.showLoading();

  // Get elements
  window.nameUserInfoConfigINP   = document.getElementById('nameUserInfoConfigINP');
  window.emailUserInfoConfigINP  = document.getElementById('emailUserInfoConfigINP');
  window.birthUserInfoConfigINP  = document.getElementById('birthUserInfoConfigINP');
[...]

and so on for as many .js files we join in a single .min.js file and finally:
  // Create a fragment to hold all HTML before appending to DOM
  let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  // Add fragment to DOM
  while(tempDIV.firstChild){ fragment.appendChild(tempDIV.firstChild); } // Move all nodes from the temporary div to the fragment
  popupPG.appendChild(fragment);`enter code here`

which, one more time, renders flawlessly on v8 and takes a crazy amount of time to integrate the HTML using Safari WebKit.
Am I mistaking something bad here or am I just stepping on the current WebKit engine limitation? I really think it is the second posibility as I have spent 6 months trying to solve this issue without success while v8 engine gives me an PWA experience indistinguishable to Native experience.
UPDATE: Even eliminating almost all the Shadows and Animations we are still facing huge renderization problems that leads to deeper buggys which happens only in WebKit...
